# How to open tkinter GUI window while opencv webcam is running?

Tags: python, opencv, user-interface, tkinter, webcam

We are now working on a thesis based on drowsiness detection within a car. Our code  is on a while loop and every time it detects up to 5 or more seconds to be driver is drowsy, the GUI must show up to alert the user that the car is slowly breaking. My problem is while the opencv webcam is runnning (for the drowsiness detection), the tkinter GUI won't show up. Is there any way to like overlap the tkinter window from the webcam frame running in the background?

Comment: Try `<tk.Tk>.attributes("-topmost", True)`

Comment: you could use queue to send some message from background to main process - and GUI would have to run loop which check queue if there is new message which it has to display. This could use `root.after(time, function)` to check queue periodically.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. 

I have two separate script tho. SCRIPT1.py for the opencv and SCRIPT2.py for the tkinter GUI. I just used importing the SCRIPT2 in the SCRIPT1 to function (def) calling.

As soon as the opencv loop stops, the GUI will appear. But I want the opencv webcam still running in the background. Is there any possibility to this?

Comment: you should write it in question when you was creating question. You wasted few hours because you didn't add it in question. Now people moved to other questions and they forgot your question and you may never get answer. It shows how important is to put ALL information in question.

Comment: `openCV` runs loop (which blocks code) and `root.mainloop()` also runs loop (which blocks code) - and both can't run in the same process. You will have to run `openCV` in separated thread (because tkinter doesn't like to run in thread other than main process). Eventually you could use `root.update()` inside `openCV` loop (instead of `root.mainloop()`) and `openCV` loop will execute it in every loop - similar to `root.mainloop()` which runs loop with `root.update()`.

Comment: probalby description in previous comment may not be so useful for you - but you didn't show minimal working code with your problem so we can't  create minimal working example for you. And agani you don't get answer because you didn't add all needed information in question.

Comment: I have some example with OpenCV + Tkinter on GitHub [furas/python-examples](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/cv2) and there is `tkinter-CV - minimal version` which runs `OpenCV` in `tkinter` - but it doesn't use standard window in `OpenCV` but it displays webcam stream directly in `tkinter` window. It uses `root.after(time, function)` to run OpenCV code periodically so it works like in loop.